# Ruby on Rails regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have these statements in a model:

```
before_save :add_http

protected
def add_http
  if (/^http\:\/\/.+$/.match(url)) == nil
    str = "http://" + url
    url = str
  end
end
```

I have checked the regex in the console and it appears to be right, but when the 'url' gets saved to the db the "http://" has not been added.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this matters to you or not, but your regex won't work with https URLs. This should work though:

```
def add_http
  self.url += "http://" if self.url.match(/^https?\:\/\/.+$/).nil?
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought about that but wanted to get the basics working first.  By the way, I read your blog about the 'pron star' fiasco, nice article!

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, got it...

```
protected
def add_http
  if (/^http\:\/\/.+$/.match(url)) == nil
    str = "http://" + url
    self.url = str
  end
end
```